# Getting user list in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, authentication

I have a Silverlight web app which uses ASP.net Website administration tool for user authentication. Now is there any way by which I can get the list of all registered users in Silverlight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write a little web service that publishes the parts of the MembershipProvider API that you need.

Comment: I am using the Silvelight Business Application template. I wrote a function which uses getUserList function to return the user list. I tried exposing it as Service using WCF. But when I try to compile the client side code it throws a warning saying "Client Proxy Generation for user_authentication.Web.Service1 failed'. Why does it happen?

Comment: I answered this in your new queston at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658656/silverlight-business-application-template-with-wcf-is-throwing-warning :->