# Silverlight Business Application template with WCF is throwing warning

Tags: wcf, silverlight

I am using the Silvelight Business Application template. I wrote a function which uses Membership.getUserList function to return the user list. I tried exposing it as Service using WCF. But when I try to compile the client side code it throws a warning saying "Client Proxy Generation for user_authentication.Web.Service1 failed'. Why does it happen?
The complete warning message is:

> Warning   4   Client proxy generation for
>   service
>   'user_authentication.Web.Service1'
>   failed: Generating metadata files...
>   Warning: Unable to load a service with
>   configName
>   'user_authentication.Web.Service1'. To
>   export a service provide both the
>   assembly containing the service type
>   and an executable with configuration
>   for this service.
>       Details:Either none of the assemblies passed were executables
>   with configuration files or none of
>   the configuration files contained
>   services with the config name
>   'user_authentication.Web.Service1'.
>
> Warning: No metadata files were
>   generated. No service contracts were
>   exported.  To export a service, use
>   the /serviceName option. To export
>   data contracts, specify the
>   /dataContractOnly option. This can
>   sometimes occur in certain security
>   contexts, such as when the assembly is
>   loaded over a UNC network file share.
>   If this is the case, try copying the
>   assembly into a trusted environment
>   and running it.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say, I'm not a good enough clairvoyant yet ;-) ... Is your webservice actually already compiled, published and running? Maybe here you can find further hints:

[MSDN WCF Forums: svcutil Error](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/3e1aac56-54a5-4838-a9dc-8638528e79a8)